# Can we assign a variable for looping to a value inside the loop in Java?

Tags: java, loops, variable-assignment

I would like to assign a certain value to an iteration variable inside a for loop in Java.

```
List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList(1,2,4,16,32,64,128);
for (Integer value: values) {
   value = value / 2;  // local value
}
```

Is this assignment working in `java`?

Comment: Add more information about `values`, expected and actual results

Comment: what is value type

Comment: Sorry what is Values type

Comment: That's not an iterator... But if you want to find out, if you can do that, why don't you just try it?

Comment: Just want some pointers to documentation about it, may be more a comprehensive answer. Since I am more familiar with C than Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't and also its not recommended however in your case

```
List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList(1,2,4,16,32,64,128);
    for (Integer value: values) {
       value = value / 2;  // local value even its modify it will not affect in collection so you will not get an error.
    }
```

Java is having **value type** and **reference type**. so if you are modifying anything inside a **foreach** loop and its **value type** it will **work** and its local value so it will not modify a collection, but if its reference type you will get an error.

In for-each loop, we can’t modify collection, it will throw a **ConcurrentModificationException** 
Modifying a collection simply means removing an element or changing content of an item stored in the collection.

If you want to modify a collection use **iterator**

if you just need traversing use **foreach**

for more please visit [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterator-vs-foreach-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by hacking your way, but it is very suspicious and if you really need this, you are probably doing something wrong.

What you may need is to have another collection where you can put processed values,

```
List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList(1,2,4,16,32,64,128);
List<Integer> newValues = new LinkedList();

for (Integer value: values) {
  newValues.add(value / 2); 
}
```

Or if you ask if you can simply reassign iterator value, sure it is possible, but again is a bit suspicious. Maybe you can use it in such a case;

```
List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList(1,2,4,16,32,64,128);

for (Integer value: values) {
  if(value > 32)
    value = 32;
  process(value); 
}
```

Since i only reassign the iterator `value` it is safe, however editing the collection during looping over it will either result in a `ConcurrentModificationException` or worse(hacky way) as you cannot always determine the behavior of your list implementation.